# Check if Digital Root of a Number is equal to the Digital Root of Sum of Prime Factor List

Tags: python

I was writing this code based on my basic understanding of Python logic. At the same time I felt the code is too long for its purpose. Could I get advise on this please?

Examples

smith_type(22) ➞ "Single Smith"
Digital root of 22 = 2 + 2 = 4
Sum of prime factors of 22 = 2 + 11 = 13
Digital root of 13 = 1 + 3 = 4
Is a Smith number without a brother

smith_type(7) ➞ "Trivial Smith"
The given number is a prime

smith_type(728) ➞ "Youngest Smith"
Digital root of 728 = 7 + 2 + 8 = 17 = 1 + 7 = 8
Sum of prime factors of 728 = 2 + 2 + 2 + 7 + 13 = 26
Digital root of 26 = 2 + 6 = 8
The number 729 is a Smith number, so 728 is the youngest brother

smith_type(6) ➞ "Not a Smith"
Digital root of 6 = 6 
Sum of prime factors of 6 = 2 + 3 = 5
Digital root of 5 = 5

```
# digital root
def digRoot(num): 
    return (num - 1) % 9 + 1 if num else 0


# digital root & sum of prime factors
def digRootPrime(num):

    primeFactSum = 0
    # primeFactLst = []

    while num % 2 == 0:
        # primeFactLst.append(2)
        primeFactSum += 2
        num /= 2

    for i in range(3, int(math.sqrt(num)) + 1, 2):
        while num % i == 0:
            # primeFactLst.append(int(i))
            primeFactSum += int(i)
            num /= i
    if num > 2:
        # primeFactLst.append(int(num))
        primeFactSum += int(num)

    if len(str(primeFactSum)) < 2:
        return primeFactSum
    else:
        return digRoot(primeFactSum)

# smith type
def smithBro(num):
    
    # not a smith
    if digRoot(num) != digRootPrime(num):
        return "Not a Smith"
    
    # youngest smith
    if digRoot(num-1) == digRootPrime(num-1):
        return "Youngest Smith"

    # oldest smith
    if digRoot(num+2) == digRootPrime(num+2):
        return "Oldest Smith"

    # trivial smith
    if num > 1:
        for i in range(2, int(num/2)+1):
            if (num % i) == 0:
                break
        else:
            return "Trivial Smith"
    
    # single smith
    for i in range(num-1, num+2):
        if digRoot(i) != digRootPrime(i):
            return "Single Smith"


print( smithBro(22) ) # single smith
print( smithBro(7) ) # trivial smith
print( smithBro(728) ) # youngest smith
print( smithBro(6) ) # not a smith
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace your digRoot with a digit sum function (to conform to the [Smith number definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_number)) and use it for both the number and its prime factors.

The primeFactors function could use a somewhat more efficient algorithm.

In order to handle the Smith brothers, you should separate the Smith detection logic from the text output (and let it flag trivial Smiths in the process):

```
def sumDigits(num):
    return num if num<10 else num%10 + sumDigits(num//10)

def primeFactors(num): # as a generator
    p,inc = 2,1
    while p*p<num:
        while num%p == 0:
            yield p
            num //= p
        p,inc = p+inc,2
    if num > 1: yield num

# -1 means prime, 1 means Smith, 0 means not Smith
def isSmith(num):
    pf = list(primeFactors(num))
    if len(pf) == 1: return -1 # trivial Smith (prime)
    return int(sumDigits(num) == sum(map(sumDigits,pf))) # 1 or 0

def smithType(num):
    smith = isSmith(num)
    if smith:
        if smith < 0:
            return f"{num} is Trivial Smith"
        if isSmith(num+1)>0 or isSmith(num-1)>0:
            return f"{num} is a Smith Brother"
        return f"{num} is a Smith number"
    return f"{num} is not a Smith number"
```

output:

```
print( smithType(22) )  # 22 is a Smith number
print( smithType(7) )   # 7 is Trivial Smith
print( smithType(728) ) # 728 is a Smith Brother
print( smithType(729) ) # 729 is a Smith Brother
print( smithType(6) )   # 6 is not a Smith number
```

*Note that, if you want to distinguish "younger" and "older" brothers, you will have to define how you would label a Smith that has both a younger and an older brother (middle child?) because there are Smith number triplets (e.g. 73615, 73616, 73617) and even quadruplets (e.g. 4463535, 4463536, 4463537, 4463538)*

Comment: I understand the above code is figuring out smith type based on true or false logic ? It does look efficient though I have not been able to read the code output based on the above. Do you mind explain to me or if theres tutorial online that describe the logic more comprehensively please? I have tried with the edited code and managed to resolve the question. what do you think?

Comment: Actually the isSmith() function returns -1, 0 or 1 (not True/False).  Since it is getting the prime factors, it can detect prime numbers (only one prime factor) and returns -1 for trivial Smiths.  I added a link to the wikipedia page on Smith Numbers.